# Exclude URLs when searching Firefox bookmarks

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarks

I'm using Firefox 66. I have more than a thousand bookmarks, and I want to search them for the term "PHP". However, hundreds of those bookmarks contain the `.php` extension in their URL (due to being served with PHP) and this causes those bookmarks to be returned as results regardless of whether their content is actually about PHP.

How can I search my bookmarks by the content of their titles while disregarding their URLs?

I would prefer a native solution to do this, but failing that, an add-on will do.

Answer (score 0):

You may try my add-on for this task -> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/at-your-command/. Run query **b name:php** to show only bookmarks whose name/title contains php. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmu8j.png.